# VS2019 New Project Templates Not Loading in v16.8.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I recently updated my vs2019 to latest version (16.8.1) but after completed update , I realized on create new project , new project templates has been not loading !
and I get this message :

[[image: screen shot from error]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huz7a.png)

I tried repair vs but it did not work :(
Before the update, nothing was wrong !

EDIT : I checked activitylog.xml but It was useless !

EDIT2 : There is activitylog.xml : [Download](https://ufile.io/clzf8rwf)

EDIT 3 : I repaired Visual Studio for the second time, but I still have the same problem!

EDIT 4 : I still can use command line for create project or run or ... . only Visual Studio have problem

Comment: do what VS told you. Open the activitylog.xml and look for errors/exceptions.

Comment: i checked activitylog.xml file but It was useless

Comment: share the log, so that we can look at it

Comment: ok . i will share now ...

Comment: @Majid, based on my research, I suggest that you can try to uninstall the vs2019 and reinstall vs2019. Somebody has met the same error, he solved the problem by this way.

Comment: @jack-j-jun-msft thanks for your research and answer . my vs19 just After the update it encountered problem . i repaired again a few minutes ago and still i have problem . i think after reinstall and update this error will be re Occurs !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new update was released a few hours ago (v16.8.2) and I just updated VS2019 from v16.8.1 to v16.8.2 And all the problems were solved :)
Thanks for guys who answered .

Comment: can you use a diff tool to see the diff between the json from 16.8.1 and 16.8.2?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Before Update My settings json file was completely empty (0KB) ! but after update it size was increased to 20KB .

Comment: @magicandre1981 I think there were other problems besides this . Finally, the problems were solved with the 400 MB update :) ty

Answer (score 2):

the xml shows the cause:

```
Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.EngineInitializationException: Error parsing the user settings file 
---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.    
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)    
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)    
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.EnsureLoaded()    
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.EnsureLoaded()    
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.get_Components()    
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.IDE.Bootstrapper.Register(Assembly assembly)    
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateEngine.Shared.Host.TemplateEngineBootstrapperFactory.TemplateEngineBoostrapper.Register(Assembly assembly)    
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateEngine.TemplateEngineHostManager.InitializeEngine()
```

So the `settings.json` from `%HOMEPATH%\.templateengine\vs\` is somehow corrupted.

[image]

As you see I have 3 of them for 16.7, 16.8.0 and 16.8.1. So it looks like the file is generated each time after VS update.

You could [try to repair it](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1319):

```
dotnet new --debug:reinit
```

If this doesn't fix it, [report it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to Microsoft so that it could be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for answer . the command not worked for me and i reported problem ti microsoft .